# Jquery on('click').... Function Execute only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got :

```
var current = $('.article.active');

$('div').on("click", function() {
    if(current.next('.article').hasClass('hide')){
        $(current).addClass('hide');
        $(current).next('.article').removeClass('hide');
    };  
});
```

And Html:

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div id="article0" class="article active"></div>
        <div id="article1" class="article hide"></div>
        <div id="article2" class="article hide"></div>
    </div>
```

So when I click on the div the code works, but only once. I want to be executed multiple times for every div.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/9xrpuru9/

Comment: current is already an object... Use **current** instead of _$(current)_

Comment: your fiddle does even works. please fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the active element in the click handler, also the active class also have to be changed

```
$('div.app').on("click", function () {
    var current = $('.article.active');
    $(current).addClass('hide').removeClass('active');
    if (current.next('.article').length) {
        $(current).next('.article').removeClass('hide').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.article:first').removeClass('hide').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t78c0697/)

Comment: This works perfect, but I got another question. Is it possible after the last div to start over again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the active class to the next article div.

You can try the following code.

```
$('.article').on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).next('.article').hasClass('hide')) {
            $(this).addClass('hide').removeClass('active');
            $(this).next('.article').removeClass('hide').addClass('active');
        };
    });
```